# Unable to import python module (.py file) from a C-Based Dynamic Link Library (DLL) called by JNI

Tags: python, c

I started on a hacking tool project that has vast types of attacks available.
I started with the attack tool part of this framework that I am most experienced in, It is MITM attack.
As you know, there is a packet handling library in Python called Scapy,
As I've already started writing code in Java and I am not that experienced in Python, I decided to Bridge the arp poisoning function from Java to Python with an intermediatory language C.
The reason why I didn't use Jython is because Jython is not up to Python version 3 and above.
And It would be a lot easier to Bridge between Java and Python using C.
Working on this, I stumbled on an issue where If I built the C program as a standalone executable and fired the `arp_poison` function in the Python ArpPoisoner.py module,
The module would load correctly by doing `PyImport_ImportModule("ArpPoisoner")`,
But if I build the program as a Dynamic Link Library (DLL), And run code from JNI (Java Native Interface),
The `PyImport_ImportFunction()` doesn't work (Meaning returns NULL), To make it easy to build a standalone executable and a DLL together from the same VS (Visual Studio) project, I Both added the main function and the `JNIEXPORT JNICALL` function,
Here's My C Script:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#include <jni.h>
#include <Python.h>

#include "net_chauhandevs_hacked_fepo_mitm_attacker_sniffing_spoofing_ArpPoisoner.h"


PyObject* ArpPoisoner;

void safeInitialize() {
    if (!Py_IsInitialized()) Py_Initialize();
}

void safeFinalize() {
    if (Py_IsInitialized()) Py_Finalize();
}

bool arp_poison(char* target_ip, char* pretend_ip) {
    printf("Working Directory: ");
    fflush(stdout);
    system("cd");
    fflush(stdout);

    safeInitialize(); //Initialize Python Interpeter

    PyObject* tempArpPoisoner = PyImport_ImportModule("ArpPoisoner");

    if (ArpPoisoner != NULL) Py_XDECREF(tempArpPoisoner); else if (tempArpPoisoner != NULL) ArpPoisoner = tempArpPoisoner; else { printf("Need to exit!\n"); exit(1); /*Code Exec Ends here If Called From JNI*/}

    PyObject* func = PyObject_GetAttrString(ArpPoisoner, "arp_poison");
    PyObject* args = PyTuple_Pack(2, PyUnicode_FromString(target_ip), PyUnicode_FromString(pretend_ip));

    PyObject* boolRs = PyObject_CallObject(func, args);
    printf("Type of PyObject: %s ", (boolRs->ob_type->tp_name));
    fflush(stdout);

    Py_XDECREF(ArpPoisoner);
    Py_XDECREF(func);
    Py_XDECREF(args);
    Py_XDECREF(boolRs);

    safeFinalize();

    return false; //Code Exec here if exec from the standalone executable.
}

JNIEXPORT jboolean JNICALL Java_net_chauhandevs_hacked_fepo_mitm_1attacker_sniffing_1spoofing_ArpPoisoner_arp_1poison(JNIEnv* env, jclass clazz,
    jstring target_ip, jstring pretend_ip) {
    char* tip = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, target_ip, 0);
    char* pip = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, pretend_ip, 0);

    arp_poison(tip, pip);

    (*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(env, target_ip, tip);
    (*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(env, pretend_ip, pip);
    return JNI_FALSE;
}

int main() {
    arp_poison("192.168.0.12", "127.0.0.1");

    return 0;
}
```

Here's My Java Code And Python Script If there could be some Issues:
Python:

```
def arp_poison(tip, pip): //Temporary Place Holder Code
    print("TIP: "+tip)
    print("PIP: "+pip)
    return False
```

Java:
Console.ExecuteCommand which forks the native method:

```
private String ExecuteCommand(String command){
    String ret = "Invalid Command!";
    if(command.equals("exit")){
        System.exit(1);
        ret = "Exiting!";
    } else if(command.equals("arp-poison")) {
        ArpPoisoner.arp_poison("192.168.0.1", "127.0.0.1");
    }
    return ret;
}
```

ArpPoisoner Class:

```
public class ArpPoisoner {
    public static native boolean arp_poison(String target_ip, String pretend_ip);
}
```

Note: System.loadLibrary() function to load the DLL (Dynamic Link Libraty) is executed in the other part of the code that I haven't shown.
If something you found helpful, please let me know,
Thanks!

Comment: As it it, this should only work if `ArpPoisoner.py` is in your current working dir. I reckon that might not be the case in your JNI run. Btw, I can image it might be problematic to reuse a `PyObject` (`ArpPoisoner`) after finalizing and re-initializing the Python interpreter.

Comment: First of all to your first solution, I have used `system("cd");` command in c code to print working dir, secondly I used `System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"));` in Java code to print working directory, The directories are the same in which ArpPoisoner.py is included, secondly, I actually ain't re-initializing after finalizing, I have implemented like so if i compile as .dll and JNI calls, the arp poisoner function in C is called, while when i compile as an .exe, `main()` calls `arp_poisoner`. Thus it is for making it easier to build to both .dll and .exe.

Comment: For one, your calls such as `safeInitialize()` are not multi-thread safe, so if you have multiple threads running you could very well be causing all kinds of problems.  And cramming an entire `if ... else ...` in to one line makes for unreadable code.

Comment: First of all, I haven't decided to go multi-threading, secondly If I've cramped up `if and else`, thats because I didn't need to go a multi-line way because each block in if else is of just one line.

Comment: Did you verify that the python search path includes the current directory?

Comment: No, how am I going to do that? You shall send this comment as an answer so I can mark it as correct if it really worked.

Comment: You'd need to translate and run `import sys; print(sys.path)` as Python C-API code. A good portion of that you already have in your above code. Also, printing the error through [`PyErr_PrintEx`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/exceptions.html#c.PyErr_PrintEx) might be helpful, in case finding the module isn't the actual problem.

Comment: Okay, so this print states that the `sys.path` doesn't include the ArpPoisoner.py's directory. You may send this as an answer and explain how we include it in the sys.path, So I could accept this as an answer and others could find it usefull.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so as [@Jeronimo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8547331/jeronimo) stated that I've to print the `sys.path` list to check weather if the ArpPoisoner directory is included or not.
After doing It, the program states that `sys.path` list doesn't contains the ArpPoisoner directory.
And here's the solution to include it in C-Python API Code:

```
/*Import CWD into sys.path*/
char cwd[FILENAME_MAX];
_getcwd(cwd, sizeof(cwd));

PyObject* sys = PyImport_ImportModule("sys");
PyObject* sys_path = PyObject_GetAttrString(sys, "path");
PyList_Insert(sys_path, 0, PyUnicode_DecodeFSDefault(cwd));
```

With include headers:

```
#include <direct.h>
```

Note: This doesn't works on any other OS except Windows.
Thank you!

Comment: Glad you got it. [This](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys_path_init.html#the-initialization-of-the-sys-path-module-search-path) is a good read. Seems like CWD is only in `sys.path` "when executing the interactive shell, a -c command, or -m module". Further down they link to [Python Path Configuration](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/init_config.html#python-path-configuration), which looks like it can be used to add CWD to search paths, too, especially for your embedding use case.